# MVC 3 and JQuery UI validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I am using MVC 3 and validating my HTML helpers on my form against the model using data annotations.  If I want to add, for example, some JQuery UI elements to my form such as a datepicker, would I be able to validate them against my model, or would I need to do client side validation?

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQuery for validation on the client side and use DataAnnotation on the server side.

You can also use the Open Source DataAnnotation for [Date](http://dataannotationsextensions.org).

Comment: Do you have an example of how to bind the JQuery control to the model?

Answer (score 0):

> would I be able to validate them against my model?

Yes... why won't you try?